# Is there a publishOnce sort of operator in RxJS?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

```
const xSubject = new BehaviorSubject(undefined);
someSource$.subscribe(xSubject);
emitWhenSomeSourceEmits$.pipe(
  concatMap(
    (emission) => of(emission)
        .pipe(
          delayWhen(
            () => someSource$.pipe(
              filter(val => !!val),
              ...
              tap(() => xSubject.next(undefined)),
            ),
        );
  ),
);
```

Expectation: emitWhenSomeSourceEmits$'s emissions should be delayed till someSource$ emits a new value.

If I do not use the BehaviorSubject, then if someSource$ emits before the emitWhenSomeSourceEmits$ does then the latter's emission is erroneously delayed till the next emission.

If I use just the BehaviorSubject, the emitWhenSomeSourceEmits' first emission will be timed with someSource. But the second emission from emitWhenSomeSourceEmits will use the Behaved value and emit anyways.

To overcome it I have been tapping an `undefined` to the xSubject so that the next emission from emitWhenSomeSourceEmits waits for a new value from someSource.

Is there a better and non-hacky way to do this?

Comment: I think you can use the [`bufferToggle`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/bufferToggle) operator. [Here's](https://stackblitz.com/edit/pjcuk3) an example. `bufferToggle(start$, end$)` will start collecting values when values when 'start$' emits and will emit the buffered values when `end$` emits. If you don't need a `start$` observable to decide when to start collecting values, you can use the `buffer` operator.

Comment: The problem is that the end$ could have emitted before the source$ emits. I need to have a 1 is to 1 relationship between the emitWhenSomeSourceEmits emissions and  someSource emissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `zip` operator (https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/zip) sounds perfect for this, so just `zip(someSource$, emitWhenSomeSourceEmits$)`.

Comment: Thank you! So simple!